# unzip file using batch

Tags: file, batch-file, unzip

I am making an program that will unzip a specific file into a folder with no add on programs/add on's

Current Code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft Games\Flight Simulator\10.0" /v 

AppPath') do set "AppPath=%%~b"
echo Installing to: %AppPath%
XCOPY "%~dp0include\HONDA_JET" "%AppPath%SimObjects\Airplanes\HondaJet" /C /S /Y /I
pause
```

i cant use any files other than batch so no vbs.

thanks

PS
Please close this thread if it is in another one and give me the link

Comment: because you use the 3rd party tool `unzip`, can you also use `7zip`?

Comment: What is `unzip.exe`?  Does it have to be only batch commands?  Because then you should be using `Expand`

Answer (score 1):

Unziping files without third party tools sample:

```
@set @e=0 /*
   @echo off
     set @e=
     setlocal
       set "i=0"
       for %%i in (%*) do set /a "i+=1"
       if "%i%" neq "2" goto:eof
       cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" %1 %2
     endlocal
   exit /b
*/

function Extract(zip, dest) {
   with (new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')) {
      if (!FolderExists(dest)) CreateFolder(dest);

   with (new ActiveXObject('Shell.Application')) {
      NameSpace(GetFolder(dest).Path).CopyHere(Namespace(GetFile(zip).Path).Items());
   }
  }
}

with (WScript.Arguments) {
  try {
    var zip = Unnamed(0), dest = Unnamed(1);
    Extract(zip, dest);
  }
  catch (e) {
  WScript.echo(e.message);
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
unzip.cmd myarc.zip foo
```